# Have long time to get metadata about 5 minutes during send play a track function

Tags: spotify, libspotify

We get application key by spotify premium acccount,and build example jukebox to test playtrack such as ./playtrack -u XXX -p YYY,listen the music about 5 minutes after send the cmd.

log first time:
./playtrack -u XXX -p YYY

05:41:21.742 I [offline_authorizer.cpp:297] Unable to login offline: no such user

05:41:21.751 I [ap:1752] Connecting to AP ap.spotify.com:4070

05:41:21.912 I [ap:1226] Connected to AP: 194.68.28.68:4070

05:41:22.650 I [user_cache:135] UserCache::initiateGetUsers() will query for 1 users

Loading track

Metadata updated, trying to start playback

Now playing "Harder Better Faster Stronger"...

05:46:24.632 I [file_streamer_simple.cpp:769] Request for file 4543d5422ace7b22147db4e793ff3aa1c22c24f2 complete (code: 0)

05:46:25.693 I [file_streamer_simple.cpp:769] Request for file 4543d5422ace7b22147db4e793ff3aa1c22c24f2 complete (code: 0)

second time:
./playtrack -u XXX -p YYY

05:48:21.974 I [ap:1752] Connecting to AP ap.spotify.com:4070

Loading track

05:48:22.135 I [ap:1226] Connected to AP: 194.68.29.22:4070

Metadata updated, trying to start playback

Now playing "Harder Better Faster Stronger"...

05:53:24.632 I [file_streamer_simple.cpp:769] Request for file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've been downvoted by other users who didn't care to give you an explanation, which doesn't help you at all. Please read this guide about how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please improve your question according to good practices and you have a higher chance of getting help.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal playback by ./jukebox -u xxx -p yyy -l ### to play playlist,but do not why wait a long time to listen the music by ./playtrack.Play track may be first create container of playlist,and then play?